# Resizing image by giving some padding for large screens with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap in my server side web application. To resize the image for large screens, I gave some padding so that it doesn't get so bigger.

Is it a good approach to resize the images or should I use other ways ?

```html
<section class="pt-8 pt-md-11">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-md-2 px-md-5 px-lg-9">
        <img src="/img/myimage.pnh" class="img-fluid mb-6 mb-md-0" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-md-1 text-center text-md-left">
        <h2 class="display-3 font-weight-bold ">Save the World</h2>
        <p class="text-muted">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

the "img-fluid" class is:

```
.img-fluid {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

So the point is the max-width. You should set it to a number that you want to prevent img to be bigger

Comment: Is it a good idea to manipulate the bootstrap classes  like `img-fluid` ? It is used all aver the application and it will be broken after manipulation. I have used the classes `px-md-5 px-lg-9` to fit the image responsively. But there are some other classes I have no idea of such that `mw-sm-75 mw-md-50` etc.

Comment: - for mw-75, mw-50 class it always resize the image or the div to 75%, 50% of the original size, so I think it isn't a good idea.
- px-5, px-9 it uses rem unit => it may not meet the requirment of size for extremely large screen
- In my opinion, percentage may be the best solution at this. Besided, obviously, you can make a global class for this too